# How to choose profile in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: spring, configuration, intellij-idea, notifications

Why IntelliJ IDEA opens a message when I open Spring configuration file and drop-down to choose a profile? And why it doesn't appear anymore if I choose close link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click "Close" on the profile pop-up, it makes a settings change and disables the panel for all spring contexts. (So you are not just closing it for that file and that viewing. IMHO "Close" is a bit of a misleading name. I think the "Close" link should be renamed to "Disable".) You can turn it back on via:  *File > Settings > [IDE Settings] > Editor > Appearance > "Show Spring Profiles panel"* (it's near the bottom)

**EDIT**

This quirk in the UI has been annoying me for a while. Answering your question made me take a minute to open a [usability -issue-report/feature-request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115151) to change it. Please vote for it.

**EDIT 2**
To answer your follow up question in your comment...

The setting is for the IDE only and does not effect anything when you run or test the code. Conversely, it does not pick up any settings from your code. It basically sets what you, IDEA, and IDEA's inspections "see". It makes it so only beans from the selected profile are "active in the IDE. This way you can switch between profiles when editing your code and configurations and get a valid representation of that profile.

For example, take a look at the screenshot below. (You may have to open it in a separate browser tab to see the detail.) In it I have the 'dev' profile active. By doing that I get the following benefits:

1. IDEA highlights that it cannot resolve a bean that I am trying to reference that I have mistakenly only defined in the (non-active) 'prod' profile. (Or the error could be that the bean has a different name in each profile.)
2. When I trigger code completion to reference another bean, IDEA only shows me beans that are available, including those in the active profile. Notice it does NOT show me the 'beanDefOnlyInProdProfile' bean since it is in an inactive profile.
   [image]

The same holds true in code completion when in Java Classes. Notice below the two code completions only show me beans from the active profile:
[image]

Comment: I was surprised when this messages appeared because I have already configured a profile in the spring context and web.xml, deployed and run it. What else it could change if I play with the dialog message or IDE settings?

Comment: The profile chooser allows you to switch profile "on-the-fly" in your IDE to verify all variations you might choose from during runtime.

Comment: Yes, Now it makes sense. Sometimes new features work like old features and this is not an exception in IDEA. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, I'd wanted this feature suspended and recurred when next time I open the editor for the context. It could be a timely setting for an hour or two or day, until I push a checkbox "don't show me again", but it should be reopened next time I open a spring context if it was not suspended or expired.

Comment: @nikpon - I recommend you make your comments/suggestions on the [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115151) I submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "Event Log" button on the bottom toolbar.  It will pop up a window with previous messages from IntelliJ.  In there will be the spring message that you saw, along with a "Configure" link.  Click on that and you'll be able to choose your profile.

Comment: Thank you for your help, It was helpful I really don't pay much attention on events run by the IDE because busy on the problems in the code. Better understanding how IDE works becomes more productive.