# Autowiring bean based on Spring Profile

Tags: java, spring, profiles

I am using Spring profiles to load the configuration file based on **spring.profiles.active**

```
<beans profile="local">
    <bean id="configurationFile" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
        <constructor-arg value="META-INF/local.yml" />
    </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="production">
    <bean id="configurationFile" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
        <constructor-arg value="META-INF/production.yml" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And then I am auto wiring

```
@Autowired
public Configs(ClassPathResource configurationFile) throws IOException {
    super(configurationFile, MyConfiguration.class);
}
```

This is working fine at runtime, but I am getting compiler errors that multiple beans are found as defined in my xml above, how can I overcome this check ?

Comment: You are getting compiler errors on an xml file? Could you post them?

Comment: @Dirk : Yes, IntelliJ is giving that same bean exists multiple times in xml as per the config posted above. Also the Java class file is giving compiler warning that "configurationFile" has multiple beans.

Comment: Then maybe InteliJ's spring support is broken...

Comment: As you can see in http://stackoverflow.com/a/19467190/1686330 this shouldn't happen. Are you using an old version of IntelliJ?

Comment: I am using latest version ..intelliJ 13